# Remove auth cookie if user is deleted

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is there a way to remove the authentication cookie, or sign a user out once they are removed from the asp.net membership database? By default if a user is removed from the database, the user can still browse the website since they still have a valid authentication cookie.

I've tried different things within `global.asax` but nothing seems to work. Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

See here: [`FormsAuthentication.SignOut Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx). Although this refers to users not being logged out server side, a similar approach can be used for managing deleted users.

> Calling the SignOut method only removes the forms authentication cookie. The Web server does not store valid and expired authentication tickets for later comparison. This makes your site vulnerable to a replay attack if a malicious user obtains a valid forms authentication cookie. To improve security when using a forms authentication cookie, you should do the following:
>
> - Use absolute expiration for forms authentication cookies by setting the SlidingExpiration property to false. This limits the window in which a hijacked cookie can be replayed.
> - Only issue and accept authentication cookies over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), by setting the RequireSSL property to true and by running the entire Web site under SSL. Setting the RequireSSL property to true ensures that ASP.NET will never send an authentication cookie to the browser over a non-SSL connection; however, the client might not honor the secure setting on the cookie. This means the client might send the forms authentication cookie over a non-SSL connection, thus leaving it vulnerable to hijack. You can prevent a client from sending the forms authentication cookie in the clear by running the entire Web site under SSL.
> - Use persistent storage on the server to record when a user logs out of the Web site, and then use an application event such as PostAuthenticateRequest event to determine whether the current user was authenticated with forms authentication. If the user was authenticated with forms authentication, and if the information in persistent storage indicates the user is logged out, immediately clear the authentication cookie and redirect the browser back to the login page. After a successful login, update storage to reflect that the user is logged in. When you use this method, your application must track the logged-in status of the user, and must force idle users to log out.

The third option is the most secure but requires the most effort. IMO, the first two do not resolve the issue adequately.

It is also possible to [store custom information in the Forms Authentication Ticket](http://www.danharman.net/2011/07/07/storing-custom-data-in-forms-authentication-tickets/). You could store the last explicit logout time in this ticket, and check it against your server side database record. Please note that if this record is at user level instead of session, then all logins under that account would be logged out at the same time.

In your case, if you are deleting server side user and session records, as the record does not exist you will be able to also fail the authentication request.

I'd advise also storing and checking the last date/time the password was changed - that way if a user updates their password then all existing sessions are logged out.